# How far could you theorically get with the one shot demo?

Tags: resident-evil-2-2019

There was the one shot demo that you could play last week.

In that demo, you had half an hour to get as far as you could in the police station.

I would imagine that even if you could speedrun pretty far in the game, you did not download the whole game in case you got that far. So it must hard block you at some point, even if there's still time on the clock.

So if you were to remove the time limit (or go really fast), how far could you theorically go in the one shot demo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funny how you may find the answer to your own question later in the day.

The GameGrumps played the 1-shot demo, and the game ended right after the cutscene where you see Claire on the surveillance camera.

And it ended with a splash screen saying complete, that I don't think I saw in other playthroughs.

[image]

So I guess that is where the Oneshot demo forces you out of the game, even if there is still time on the clock.

Fun fact, earlier in the video there were 6 minutes left, so the completion timer must not count some things (even if the oneshot timer seems to continue) I would guess the completion timer pauses in cutscenes and the one shot doesnt; because the only other place I can think of is when you pause the game, but that also pauses the oneshot timer.